# Using google datastore to check items in streaming mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to insert items into Google Datastore if they don't exist in it.
I write a dataflow streaming job.

**Job**

```
static class RawToObjectConverter extends DoFn<String, Entity> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {      

        Query<Entity> query = Query.entityQueryBuilder().kind("Post").filter(PropertyFilter.eq("postid", rq.postid))
                .build();
        QueryResults<Entity> posts = datastore.run(query);

        if (posts == null || !posts.hasNext()) {
            Entity post = Entity.builder(datastore.newKeyFactory().newKey("Post"))                 
                     .set("postid", "1")
                    .set("title", "p1")
                    .build();
            c.output(post);
        }           
    }
}
```

**Problem**

```
lines.apply(ParDo.of(new RawToObjectConverter()))
    .apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(projectid));
```

The method `apply(PTransform<? super PCollection<Entity>,OutputT>)` in the type `PCollection<Entity>` is not applicable for the arguments (`DatastoreV1.Write`)

Also should I use `com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore` or `com.google.datastore.v1.Entity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to convert your *com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity* to *com.google.datastore.v1.Entity* in *RawToObjectConverter* before using *DatastoreIO.v1().write()*,
using [toPb](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseEntity.java#L680) method

```
c.output(post.toPb());
```

Comment: It gives me an error: "The method to Pb() from the type BaseEntity<Key> is not visible"

Comment: @KassemShehady looks like it is not a public method. Checking with Datastore team if there is an alternative. For the time being you could write this method yourself, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseEntity.java#L680